# Converting integer array to byte array

Tags: java, android

I'm currently writing a small application that interacts with a Windows driver via a callback. This application records various XY coordinates and button states, which are expressed in integers. The application will send this this data to callback via a local network. My experience with packets is limited to say the least, but I at least know that I need to convert the values into a byte array.

For example, below are two sets of arrays:

```
int[][] axes = { {75, 150}, {0, 40} };

int[] buttons= {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}
```

How exactly would I go about converting these values into a byte array? Also, what use do offsets serve? I've looked around and I can't quite get my head around it.

Comment: All the answers assume that you don't mind using 4 bits for every integer (even if it could be converted using one byte) . If you have a large array of low-valued integers, you might want to check out another solution using bit-coding on the highest-order bits but I don't have enough time to write it right now. If you still want to find out about it in the evening I'll post it.

Comment: @NitroNbg I managed to figure it out. Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert int to byte[].
create this function:

```
byte[] toBytes(int i)
{
  byte[] result = new byte[4];

  result[0] = (byte) (i >> 24);
  result[1] = (byte) (i >> 16);
  result[2] = (byte) (i >> 8);
  result[3] = (byte) (i /*>> 0*/);

  return result;
}
```

Run in a loop on your int[], for each cell call to the function and add result to an array of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all the elements of the array and then extract the bytes one by one of each integer. Assuming an integer is 4 bytes, you could use bit shifting operations and extract each 8 bits from the integer. After that, using the byte data type you can create arrays.

e.g. a =  10110011    11101010    11110101       11010100 //in binary

```
      byte 3    byte 2  byte 1  byte 0
```

byte 0 = a & 0xFF

byte 1 = (a >> 8) & 0xFF

byte 2 = (a >> 16) & 0xFF

byte 3 = (a >> 24) & 0xFF

To convert back to integer, for each set of 4 bytes in the bytes array:

number = 
(byte3 << 24) | (byte2 << 16) | (byte 1 << 8) | byte0

Comment: True and for recompiling it back to integer would be `int originalInt = byte0 | (byte1 << 8) | (byte2 << 16) | (byte3 << 24)`